# bazel query to list all dependencies for a target along with version of the dependency

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

looking for a way to get list of all external dependencies along with the version (defined in build file) of the dependencies for the target.

`bazel query "kind(rule, deps(//foo:target))" --output=package`
only returns list of dependencies.

is there a way to log dependency:version during the build?

Comment: "external dependencies along with the version (defined in build file)", how is the version information defined in the build file? That is, what rules are you using? Bazel itself (e.g. `bazel query`) doesn't have any special treatment of version information, it's up to the rules. E.g. the `artifacts` attribute of the `maven_install` rule of the `rules_jvm_external` ruleset is just a list of strings to `bazel query`, rather than a list of maven coordinates (which have version information).

Comment: **python_binary(
    name = "xyz",
    pip_version = "1.0.1",
    deps = [
        "//abc",
    ],
)**
external dependency is defined in this format ^. is there a query to pull the list of dependencies for a target something like //xyz=1.0.1 ?

Comment: What ruleset are you using? Is it a `WORKSPACE` rule or a `BUILD` rule? I couldn't find a ruleset that has "python_binary" and "pip_version", so is this a ruleset you wrote yourself? Depending on the type and implementation of the rule, you could do `bazel cquery <query> --output=starlark --starlark:expr="print(providers(target)[something])"` where `something` is some provider that provides version information. If there's no such provider and you can't modify rules, then you'd likely use an Aspect

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on the version of the bazel python rules you're using, but we use a query like so just to get deps in the format that have their name and version

```
bazel query "deps(kind(rule, deps(//foo:target)))"
```

This produces output that contains lines like

```
@requirements_werkzeug_3_0_1_py3_none_any_whl//file:werkzeug-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

The bit after the `:` is essentially the filename and the package. With a bit of bash I can get basically what you're after

```
bazel query "deps(kind(rule, deps(//foo:target)))" | \
  grep whl | grep -v "file:file" | \
  cut -d ":" -f2 | cut -d"-" -f1-2 | tr "-" ":"
```

Which produces output that looks like

```
werkzeug:3.0.1
```